# typescript narrow string type to be member of one enum

Tags: typescript, enums

I have a function that takes a string and it is supposed to call another function that only accepts values of two enum.

How can I narrow down the string type to be a type compatible with an enum? I tried with object.values but typescript doesn't seem to like in in any way I try.

[Here is a little example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwIJwN4Cg5wCGcAvHAESHkA0%20cARqRfTXQMZPlusC%20uuoSLAQp0ADRx0QnEKwIBPTvLlwAXp1W9%20g6PDYREAZ3gAVJtjgA6axmpXrEnkUNx9RmAG5%20AM2SI2MACWBnDeEBAAFDAAXHDGUIGIAOYAlLESAD6YkgSB3nARAPL0AFbAAZYAboQANsjAhhFiKZaJbHUAJg1RznDNKTkEcFDAMMhQiHAwdHy53kWl5TBVtfWNGC1tnd0wKSl4Q8Oj45PTBLNHYxN9liC4fEA)

```js
export enum A {
  a = "a",
  b = "b",
  c = "c",
}

export enum X {
  x = "x",
  y = "y",
  z = "z",
}

export const T = { ...A, ...X } as const;

function foo(t: string): X | A {
  if (Object.values(X).includes(t as X)) {
    return t
  }
  if(Object.values(A).includes(t)){
    return t
  }
  return X.x
}
```

Of course I can write a type guard function, but that is just cheating to me as I have to manually take care that the function code is correct and that, effectively, it correctly narrows down the string to be in one of the enums. So this is what I want to avoid:

```js
function isXorA (t: string): t is X | A {
    if (Object.values(X).includes(t as X)) {
    return true
  }
  if(Object.values(A).includes(t as A)){
    return true
  }
  return false
}


function foo(t: string): X | A {
if(isXorA(t)){
  return t
}
  return X.x
}
```

Comment: The intent of `enum` is that you get a nominal-ish type not seen to be equivalent to the corresponding string/numeric literal.  That is, it is the intended behavior that `const oops: A.a = "a"; // Type '"a"' is not assignable to type 'A.a'.` be an error.  Since you are trying to circumvent the point of an enum, the only way to do it is with something inherently unsafe like a type assertion or a type guard function.  [(assertion example)](https://tsplay.dev/wXKn1W) Does that address your question or am I missing something?

Comment: If that is the intended behaviour of enums then they can never be used (safely) with any code that interacts with any third party, let that be the user or an API.

Comment: Right, third parties should not know about the particular enum values you are using; they are essentially nominal types and opaque.  Anywhere you violate that you will need to do something inherently unsafe, which doesn't mean you should never do it, just that you need to be careful.  I'm not sure if your comment means you don't believe that enums are meant to be this way (and thus I should add sources if I write up an answer) or that you are just unhappy about it (which, though understandable, doesn't have any bearing on the potential for answering the question). What should I do, here?

Comment: I'm upset about it because I just rewrote some code to use enums and they are way more limited than I expected. I never see a compeling reason to use an enum over a sum type, and I'm a bit upset that I should just used a sum type. You can add an answer explaining that enums are not supposed to be used like that and that I should use sum types instead.

Comment: Yeah I almost never recommend using enums since their supported use cases are quite particular and weird.  An object of string literals like `const A = {a:"a",b:"b",c:"c"} as const; type A = typeof A[keyof typeof A];` will probably serve you better. I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: Actually, backing up, TypeScript doesn't use `Array.prototype.includes(x)` as a type guard on `x`, so even using string literals won't fix it for you.  You could introduce your own `includes()` type guard function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOPB6N), which is a little unsafe but at least you only need one `includes()` in existence and it's not specific to your enum.  Do you want that as part of an answer?   Then you can still use enums like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLlaZm).  Or should I just run away screaming? 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of ChatGPT today I wrote two generic typeguards, that should work with any enum:

```
const isValueOfStringEnum = <T extends Record<string, string>>(enumType: T, value: string): value is T[keyof T] => 
   Object.values<string>(enumType).includes(value);
```

```
const isValueOfNumericEnum = <T extends Record<string, number | string>>(enumType: T, value: number): value is Exclude<T[keyof T], string> => 
  (Object.values(enumType) as Array<number | string>).filter((v): v is number => typeof v === "number").includes(value);
```

String and numeric enums work a bit differently (reverse mapping), which is why the numeric variant is a bit more complicated.

Comment: As someone downvoted this answer, I tried to find out why and found out that stackoverflow has banned the use of ChatGPT, which I was unware of when I posted this answer. I tried to delete it now, but I can't because it has been accepted as answer. If someone with more privileges wants to delete this, feel free.